# GitHub/Kiwi TCMS integration, endless spinner

Tags: kiwi-tcms

It seems that there is some issue with integration between Kiwi and GitHub.

I've added GitHub as bug tracker as follows:

Name = GitHub

Description = none

URL Format String = https://mygit/issues

RegExp for ID validation = ^\d$

Type = GitHub

Base URL = https://mygit/issues

API URL = https://api.github.com/myrepo

APi username = my username

API token = my token

When I want to add bug to Test Case:

1. I click bug -> Add
2. Select GitHub
3. Write issue number e.g. "2516"

Result: I am getting endless loading spinner and in log I see this:

> 172.20.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2019:14:04:56 +0000] "GET /case/3/execution-detail-pane/?case_run_id=2205&case_text_version=3
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 8802 "https://10.113.39.37/runs/7/" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36"
>
> 172.20.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2019:14:04:56 +0000] "GET /case/3/execution-detail-pane/?case_run_id=2205&case_text_version=3
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 8802 "https://10.113.39.37/runs/7/" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0):

Endless spinner means an internal server error and you need to check error logs for that.

From what I can see your URL format string is wrong b/c it doesn't include format placeholder. E.g. something like %d. See the help text under that field in the admin panel.